# Merge Grails request body and params into single command?

Tags: grails, command, parameters, actionmethod

Currently in my action method I unmarshal the request body and request params into two separate commands.

```
def someAction(BodyCommand bodyCmd) {
    ParamsCommand paramsCmd = new ParamsCommand(params)

    // Do something with bodyCmd and paramsCmd after
    // validating both
    if (bodyCmd.validate() && paramsCmd.validate()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I'd like to combine the commands and instead have just a single command.

```
def someAction(ActionCommand cmd) {
    cmd.merge(params)

    // Do something with cmd after validation
    if (cmd.validate()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is it possible to merge the `params` into the request body command that's automatically unmarshalled by Grails?

Comment: unsure if bindData will help http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Controllers/bindData.html

Comment: if you have controller action with command(s) as a parameter, it will be binded automatically, what more do you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Grails 2.5.0 *does* support [a simple way to merge params](http://docs.grails.org/2.5.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/properties.html) into a domain class or command object.

```
cmd.properties = params
```